# Need a way to get the display method filled with data to display on a jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i am working on a bank application. I have most of the business objects working correctly, although i cant seem to figure out how to get the display method to print to the client and not to the server log. This may seem easy to most but i am kinda stuck.

This is the jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import= "business.AccountList" %>
<%@page import= "business.Customer" %><!--Space between =" makes the String orange-->
<%@page import= "business.Account" %><!--Space between =" makes the String orange
                                       or black.--> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

    <html lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="description" content="Display Accounts Page" />
      <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Java" />
      <meta name="author" content="Robert McGuire " />
      <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Display Accounts Page</title>
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_General.css" />-->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
</head>
    <body>
        <%
            Customer c1 = (Customer)session.getAttribute("c1");
            out.println("Customer object from session:"+c1);
            //Account a1 = (Account)session.getAttribute("a1");
            //out.println("Account object from session:"+a1);
            //c1.display();
            //c1.list.arr[0].display();
            int c =c1.list.count;
            for(int i =0; i<c;i++){
                c1.list.arr[i].display();
            }
            %>

            <h1>Welcome <%=c1.getCustFirstName()%>    <%=c1.getCustLastName()%> .</h1>
            <p>Address : <%=c1.getAddress()%> </p>
            <p>Email : <%=c1.getEmail()%> </p>

            <h2>Your Account details are listed here.</h2>
        <!--Form Section.-->
        <div>

          <!--  <form action="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication12/AccountLookupServlet" method="post">
                <pre>
                Account No: <input type="text" name="accountNumber" placeholder="Account ##"><br>
                Customer ID:<input type="text" name="custId" placeholder="Customer ID"/><br>
                Type:       <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Account Type"/><br/>
                Balance:    <input type="text" name="balance" placeholder="Balance"/>
                <br/>        
                            <input type="submit" value="Retrieve" /><input type="reset" value="Clear" />
                </pre>
            </form>-->
        </div>
        <!--putting the acct info back into the page not into the textboxes. -->
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>Account Information</thead>
                <hr/>
                <br/>  
                <tr>Account Number:<%= c1.list.arr[c]%></tr><br/>
           <tr> _________Display___________</tr><br/>
           <tr> Customer Id:<%c1.getCustId(); %></tr><br/>
<%--            <tr> Account Type:<%c1.getAccounts() %> --%>

<!-- Info:   Account Type: Checking -->
<!-- Info:   Account Balance: 1000.0 -->
            </table>


        </div>
             <%
             //Putting the objects back into the session . 
             session = request.getSession();
             //session.setAttribute("a1", a1);
             session.setAttribute("c1", c1);



             %>



        <hr />
      <!--Footer section with all the navigation links.-->
        <footer>
            <a href="index.jsp" style="text-decoration: none">Homepage</a>
            <a href="login.jsp" style="text-decoration: none">Login Page</a> 
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The console display works... i just cant figure out how to get the data from the Account object to the jsp.

Ive tried to add the JspWriter as an argument accepted by the display (). I got nowhere. I have been reading about this JspWriter, and dont understand how to correctly use it. All i want to do is access:

```
 public void display() {
        System.out.println("_________Display___________");
        System.out.println("                           ");
        System.out.println("Account Number: " + getAccountNo());
        System.out.println("Customer Id:" + getCustomerID());
        System.out.println("Account Type: " + getAccountType());
        System.out.println("Account Balance: " + getBalance());
```

this from the provided jsp page. I dont know how to use the JspWriter to accomplish this task.

Sincere thanks.

ps.I am going to use scriptlet tags until i understand the other technologies. I was never informed that using scriptlet tags was bad practice.

Comment: display() would need to take the JSP writer as argument, and print to that instead of, I guess, System.out. But really, if you're starting a new project, start of good bases and stop using scriptlets in JSPs. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL. Use MVC.

Comment: How would the display() take the JSP writer as an argument, and what does that mean?

Comment: Like any method would take any argument: `void display(JspWriter out) { ... }` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Ive tried what you mentioned, and read most of those articles you referred me to and still don't understand how to use the JspWriter.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Adding the argument, instantiating JspWriter at the top of Accounts.Class. With a lack of knowledge, ive had to read and read. While not understanding how to use the JspWriter, theres not many examples.

Comment: Don't instantiate JspWriter. The JSP provides the JspWriter. In your JSP, `out` is the JspWriter. You only need to pass it as argument to your display() method.

Comment: oh you mean just the out like this??? display(out)?